# Cannot get /path on reload

Tags: express, vue-router

I have a vue front-end which runs on port 8080 and back-end which runs on port 8000. I have set up a proxy to connect the two. The issue arises when I reload the page. On reloading, it shows 'Cannot Get /path' despite the presence of wildcards on both client side and server side. When I try to send the get request directly to port 8000 using postMan, it works correctly. But when I do the same on port 8080 it shows the error. I think the issue is with the request being sent to port 8080 only, rather than being directed to port 8000.

vue (main.js)

```
let routes=[
    {
        path: '/home',
        component: () => import('./components/home.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        component: () => import('./components/signInWithRedirect.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/selectOne',
        component:() => import('./components/selectionPage.vue'), 
        props: true,
        meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
        component: () => import('./components/home.vue')
    }
];
```

server

```
let path = require('path');
let express = require("express");
let app = express();

app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './assets')));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello!');
})
```

[image: postMan]